# Googletag is not defined in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I'm getting this error: googletag is not defined in my wordpress page. I made 3 sites, and I use the same template, but in only one it's now working.

I'm pasting this code in the header with the plugin WP headers and Footers:

```
 <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

and this is the part that shows the error in google console.

```
googletag.cmd.push(function(){googletag.defineSlot("/70557531/mnd_home_728x90_D1",[728,90],"div-gpt-ad-X6451308XXXXX-0").addService(googletag.pubads());googletag.defineSlot("/70557531/mnd_home_300x600_D",[300,600],"div-gpt-ad-X645XXXX47609-0").addService(googletag.pubads());googletag.defineSlot("/70557531/mnd_home_300x250_D",[300,250],"div-gpt-ad-X6451XXXX3035-0").addService(googletag.pubads());googletag.defineSlot("/70557531/mnd_home_970x250_D2",[970,250],"div-gpt-ad-X6452XXXX9076-0").addService(googletag.pubads());
```

Comment: Can you add the screenshot in devtool - element ? We might need to see the actual code in the header

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to set up the `googletag.cmd` array in case that line of code runs before `gpt.js` loads.

Somewhere in your code before you run `googletag.cmd.push(...)`, do this to set it up:

```
window.googletag = window.googletag || {}
window.googletag.cmd = window.googletag.cmd || []
```

`gpt.js` will then run any functions in the `cmd` array when it loads.